# How to find dependent procedures on a table in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, database-schema

How can I find dependent procedures on a table in PostgreSQL?

The PostgreSQL version I am using is 8.1.

Comment: Please clarify this contradictory question. 8.1 or 8.4? Dependent how?

Comment: Suppose I am referring a table emp in a procedure get_emp_name and many other procedures. Now I want to alter the structure of a emp table. But I am not sure which all procedure/function will be impacted by the altering the emp table. Is there any way by which I can know all the procedure that are referring table emp.  In case of oracle there is a dictionary table all_dependency, not sure how to check these is postgresql

Comment: I removed the contradicting the question tag.

Answer (score 2):

There are direct dependencies for many objects like views, types or foreign key constraints in the system catalog. But the body of a plpgsql function is just a string that is executed when the function is called (plus some more magic). I quote [the manual on `CREATE FUNCTION`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createfunction.html):

> A string constant defining the function; the meaning depends on the
>   language. It can be an internal function name, the path to an object
>   file, an SQL command, or text in a procedural language.

You can create a schema-only backup of your database and search the dump with an editor or tool of your choice. Like with `grep` or `vim`.

For example, to dump the schema of a database:

```
pg_dump $DB -p $PORT -s -f /path/to/output/db_schema.pgsql
```

`-s` is for `--schema-only`. [More about pg_dump in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-pgdump.html).

Comment: Hey Thank Erwin... that was really use full to me.